# If condition in Octave is not saving the required values within an array

Tags: arrays, csv, octave

I have a `csv` file from which I want to get just the values different from `0` and save them within an array `x`. I want to store rest of the matrix elements in an array `s`. This is the code I'm running in `Octave`:

```
clear all;close all;clc;

datafile = csvread('data20us.csv');
datafile = datafile(3:length(datafile));

for i=1:length(datafile)
   if (datafile(i) ~= 0)
     % x must stock values different from 0
     x(i) = datafile(i);
   else
     % s must stock the rest of the values
     s(i) = datafile(i);
   end 
end
```

The problem I have is that the vector `x` gets filled with both `0` and non `0` values (there 20 values different from `0` in the file). Is there any mistake in the condition I'm putting in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you see zeros and non-zeros is the way you are populating the array in the loop.  If you read your code, if the value at position `i` in your CSV file (I'm assuming this is a row or column vector) is not equal to 0, position `i` of the vector `x` gets changed.  Else, position `i` of the vector `s` gets changed.  Because you are not pre-allocating the vector `x`, what happens is that the vector `x` should you specify a position that is larger than the length of the array gets populated by zeros up until the desired position which you finally store the value.

Observe:

```
>> clear x;
>> x(4) = 3
x =

   0   0   0   3

>> x(7) = 10
x =

    0    0    0    3    0    0   10
```

As you can see, by not pre-allocating `x` and you specify a position other than the first to place a value there, all positions in between the previous last element and your desired position get populated with zeros.  Therefore, when you get to a point in your loop where you have a value that's not equal to 0, you are seeing this zeros expansion happening.

If what I'm reading about your post is correct, you want to **filter out** the values in the CSV file that are not equal to 0.  This can be done with simple logical indexing:

```
x = datafile(datafile ~= 0);
```

This will give you the vector `x` with all zero values removed.  Finally, you can create the `s` vector which is just a vector of zeros that is as long as the total number of zeroes in the vector.

```
s = zeros(1, nnz(datafile == 0));
```

If you are somehow dead set on using a loop, consider **concatenating** the values instead:

```
clear all;close all;clc;

datafile = csvread('data20us.csv');
datafile = datafile(3:length(datafile));

% New - Make x empty
x = [];
% New - Make s empty
s = [];

for i=1:length(datafile)
   if (datafile(i) ~= 0)
     % x must stock values different from 0
     % New - concatenate
     x = [x datafile(i)];
   else
     % s must stock the rest of the values
     % New - concatenate
     s = [s datafile(i)];
   end 
end
```